# How to optimize all javascript files in a directory with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a folder structure like this:

```
.
├── autocomplete
│   ├── core.js
│   ├── search.js
│   └── user.js
├── build.js
├── collapsible_lists.js
├── griffgrabber
│   ├── canvasobject.js
│   ├── cargame.js
│   ├── car.js
│   ├── griffDrawer.js
│   ├── keylistener.js
│   ├── run.js
│   └── victim.js
├── main.js
├── newsfeed.js
├── require.js
├── shortcut.js
└── sidebar.js

3 directories, 20 files
```

main.js is the startup file. That file requires a couple of the files, but not all of them. The rest of the files are included with

```
<script>
    require(['shortcut'], function(shortcut){
        // ...
    })
</script>
```

in some html files.

This is my build.js file so far:

```
{
    baseUrl: ".",
    name: "main",
    out: "main-built.js",
}
```

But it only includes the files that are required by main.js. Is it possible to optimize all the javascript files in one run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(to expand @Ryan Lynch's suggestion)*:

Use the `include` option, as per the documentation:

> You can always explicitly add modules that are not found via the optimizer's static analysis by using the **include** option.

(http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html)

```
{
    baseUrl: ".", // ?
    appDir: ".", // ?
    dir: "output/",
    modules: [
        {
            name: "main",
            include: [ "shortcut" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

More detailed example in the excellent [example.build.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L353) (I actually find it more useful than the documentation page)

---

*(sorry, had no time to replicate and test properly to make sure the paths values are correct, I'll try that later and update my answer)*

Answer (score 0):

Try including a modules array in your options, so:

```
{
    baseUrl: ".",
    out: "main-built.js",
    modules: [
        {
            name: "main"
        }
    ]
}
```

As per the documentation:

> In the modules array, specify the module names that you want to
>   optimize, in the example, "main". "main" will be mapped to
>   appdirectory/scripts/main.js in your project. The build system will
>   then trace the dependencies for main.js and inject them into the
>   appdirectory-build/scripts/main.js file.

Comment: The build file you posted won't work for me.

It seems like if I use modules, I have to drop the 'out' statement and add a 'dir' statement. When I use 'dir', it optimizes the whole directory and copies the optimized files to another directory. But it does not include every file into the main-built.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Another - less orthodox - way of achieving this would be to add this `"shortcut"` module as a dependency to any of the "visible" modules that are discovered by `r.js` scanning (i.e. "main.js"). This way the entire dependency branch starting at "shortcut" would be included in the output.